# Duvida em um programa em C!!! Lista simplesmente encadeada!

Tags: c

Estava tentando fazer uma lista encadeada, mas não estou conseguindo fazer com que ela insira ou imprima ela. Se alguém puder trazer uma luz para o meu programa eu agradeço.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct cel celula;
    struct cel{
         int dado;
         celula *prox;
         };

    void inicializar(celula *p,celula *aux);
    int inserir(celula *p,celula *aux,int count,int valor);
    void imprimir(celula *p,celula *aux,int count);

    main()
    {
    celula *p, *aux;
    int count=0,chave,valor;

    inicializar(&p,&aux);

    printf("Digite o tipo de entrada:\n");
    printf("1 - Inserir numero;\n");
    printf("2 - Imprimir lista de numeros;\n");
    printf("3 - Sair.");
    while(chave!=3)
    {Restart:
    printf("\nInsira a chave: ");
    scanf("%d",&chave);
    switch(chave){
        case 1:
           printf("\nDigite o valor a ser inserido: ");
           scanf("%d",&valor);
           count=inserir(&p,&aux,count,valor);
           break;

        case 2:
           imprimir(&p,&aux,count);
           break;

        case 3:
           printf("\nPrograma encerrado!\n");
           break;

        default:
           printf("\nChave incorreta!\n");
           goto Restart;
         }
      }
   }

   void inicializar(celula *p,celula *aux)
   {
      p=NULL;
      aux=NULL;

   }

   int inserir(celula *p,celula *aux,int count,int valor)
   {
   if(count == 0)
       {p=(celula *)malloc(sizeof(celula));
       aux=p;
       p->dado=valor;
       p->prox=NULL;
       printf("%d/%d",p->dado,count);
       getch();
       count ++;
       return count;
       }
       else
       {aux->prox=(celula *)malloc(sizeof(celula));
       aux=aux->prox;
       aux->dado=valor;
       printf("%d/%d",aux->dado,count);
       getch();
       aux->prox=NULL;
       count ++;
       return count;
       }
   }

   void imprimir(celula *p,celula *aux,int count)
   {
   int i;

   for(i=0;i<count;i++)
      {printf("%d ",p->dado);
      p->prox;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

### Inicializar a lista

É possível verificar facilmente alguns erros de implementação como na função `incializar`, onde você não aloca memória para os ponteiros. Veja um exemplo de como pode ser feita tal função.

Tome uma struct `celula_s` como segue:

```
typedef struct celula_s{

    int          valor;
    struct nodo  *prox;

} lista_t;
```

Então a função `inicializar` pode ser implementada, alocando memória para o ponteiro do tipo lista utilizando a função `malloc` :

```
lista_t* lista_inicializar(void){
    lista_t* lista = (lista_t *) malloc( sizeof (lista_t) );
    lista->valor = 0;
    lista->prox = NULL;
    return lista;
}
```

---

### Inserir na lista

Agora vamos implementar uma função `inserir`. Em uma lista simplesmente encadeada você pode criar uma função para inserir em qualquer que seja a posição, então aqui vou mostrar como implementar uma função para inserir elementos no inicio da lista.

Primeiramente precisamos de uma célula ou nó ao qual será a "cabeça" da lista, nesta implementação o próximo nó da "cabeça" será o inicio da lista que temos até agora, ou seja, ele será no novo primeiro nó:

```
lista_t* lista_inserir_inicio(lista_t* lista, int valor){
    lista_t* novo = lista_inicializar();

    if(novo != NULL){
        novo->valor = valor;
        novo->prox = lista;
        lista = novo;
    }

    return lista;
}
```

---

### Imprimir a lista

Para imprimir a lista precisamos de um ponteiro auxiliar do tipo lista `aux`, ele apontará para a lista a qual queremos imprimir, então, enquanto o proximo elemento do ponteiro `aux` que está apontando para a lista não for `NULL` imprima essa célula e passe para a próxima.

```
int lista_imprimir(lista_t* lista){
    lista_t* aux;
    aux = lista;
    printf("[");
    while (aux->prox != NULL){
        printf(" %d ", aux->valor);
        aux = aux->prox;
    }
    printf("]\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Você pode conferir o código na integra nesse [link](https://ideone.com/E8oqOB).

Att.